# How to add class after ng-click to parent element in dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have multiple video player in single page. If i use jQuery it is very easy find parent element dynamically. But in Angularjs its not happening.

```
    <div class="item-media video-item" ng-class="{'active': isActive}">
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gvI2ClWqHO0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="250"></iframe>
         <img src="img/thomas-theatrics.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="play-icon" ng-click="isActive = !isActive"><img src="img/play-icon.png" alt="" class="custom-icon"></div>
    </div>

<div class="item-media video-item" ng-class="{'active': isActive}">
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gvI2ClWqHO0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="250"></iframe>
         <img src="img/thomas-theatrics.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="play-icon" ng-click="isActive = !isActive"><img src="img/play-icon.png" alt="" class="custom-icon"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. They should both have their own 'active' class because what you're missing from jQuery is the 'this', if that makes sense.

Comment: I need to implement this without jQuery @JonEdwards.

Comment: I understand. If you have isActive1 and isActive2, and set them accordingly in your ngClick, it should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Because your element structures are very similiar, you could make a directive with an isolate scope.

```
angular.module('media', [])
.directive('mediaVideo', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div class="item-media video-item" ng-class="{'active': isActive}">'+
         '<iframe ng-src="{{ iframeSrc }}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="250"></iframe>'+
         '<img src="img/thomas-theatrics.jpg" alt="">'+
         '<div class="play-icon" ng-click="isActive = !isActive"><img src="img/play-icon.png" alt="" class="custom-icon"></div>'+
         '</div>',
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: 'true',
    scope:{
        iframeSrc: '='
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attributes){
    },
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.isActive = false;
    }
  };
});
```